# Any way to force grep to understand Windows line endings?

Tags: grep, line-endings, git-for-windows

I recently installed PortableGit from GitForWindows after finding out that Github for Windows is no longer packaging the Git Shell (which I had grown rather fond of). I would like to be able to grep my source files for text at the end of a line: e.g. `grep -R -n --include "*.py" -P ":$" .`. As written, that doesn't work due to the Windows line endings - I must use `":\r$"` (or perhaps something fancier, to be more robust) instead. This is irritating; I find it hard to remember and I don't need such a workaround in gVim. I don't recall needing to do it with the grep utility built into Git Shell, either; but PortableGit's tools appear to play rather strictly by the book.

Is there any way I can force `grep` to treat `\r\n` as an end-of-line, or failing that any other amelioration here? I would prefer not to convert all my source to Unix file endings; but if that's what it takes then I would also need help in getting gVim to respect that convention (including for new files). (That's still not ideal, though; I also may want to grep the program output, and since I'm writing files in text mode in Python, they have Windows line endings naturally.)

Comment: You may use [`pcregrep`](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html) to force line endings using `-N` option. Like  `pcregrep -N CRLF 'regex' file`

Comment: I thought that git for windows (!) and generally msys/msys2 tools are more tolerant towards line endings than cygwin. You could experiment with the fstab settings (there is a binary mount flag).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set a line break sequence other than the default one with [`grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html).

However, you may do it with [`pcregrep`](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html). To force CRLF line endings, use the `-N` option like this:

```
pcregrep -N CRLF 'regex' file
```

Or, if you want to set it to CR (as on old MacOS):

```
pcregrep -N CR 'regex' file
```

Comment: `pcregrep` doesn't appear to be provided with PortableGit. Where is the best/most trustworthy source for it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Right, if you use [this one](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep), it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Run `dos2unix` to convert the file to UNIX line endings then grep on the new file.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: @mishsx the answer is effectively "rather than forcing grep to understand the existing line endings, just convert them to what grep understands".